# same code for NumberPicker looks differently on different projects?

Tags: android, numberpicker

Help! in the first project the NumberPicker behaviour is that you can change the number by pressing + or - while in the second project the NumberPicker has 3 numbers and every time you roll it, the middle number changes to the correct one. Both projects use the same NumberPicker code!!

[image: second]

[image: first]

Comment: you need to post code.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior and appearance of `NumberPicker` depends on the theme that is in effect. From [the docs for `NumberPicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html):

> - If the current theme is derived from [`Theme`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme) the widget presents the current value as an editable input field with an increment button above and a decrement button below. Long pressing the buttons allows for a quick change of the current value. Tapping on the input field allows to type in a desired value.
> - If the current theme is derived from [`Theme_Holo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Holo) or [`Theme_Holo_Light`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Holo_Light) the widget presents the current value as an editable input field with a lesser value above and a greater value below. Tapping on the lesser or greater value selects it by animating the number axis up or down to make the chosen value current. Flinging up or down allows for multiple increments or decrements of the current value. Long pressing on the lesser and greater values also allows for a quick change of the current value. Tapping on the current value allows to type in a desired value.

You evidently have different themes in effect for the `NumberPicker` in the two projects. More information is available in the [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) guide topic.